# why does the mdspan accessor policy concept contain a decay member?

Tags: c++, std, standards, mdspan

I am looking forward to the proposed mdspan, and was thinking of a toy example. What I thought of was game of life, which works on a binary 2d array. Naturally I would like to use an mdspan over a `bitset` or `std::vector<bool>`, both of which address individual bits via funky iterators. Now I was thinking I could do that by providing a suitable AccessPolicy, but as it turns out (in 26.7 [here](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2019/p0009r9.html)) AccessorPolicy has a decay member which returns a real pointer to an element type, which basically does not exist for `std::vector<bool>`. Furthermore I looked at the only Implementation I could find on [github](https://github.com/kokkos/mdspan) and while it defines this member for accessor_basic (the only required model) it actually never uses it in the mdspan implementation.

now I am bonked as to why they did that, thereby forbidding any proxy iterators, while not even needing this for mdspan? Is it for allowing use of `memcpy` in certain cases? If so, why not allow "opt-in"?

Comment: In [P0009r6](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2018/p0009r6.html), AccessorPolicy has a lot fewer requirements and no `decay()` method.  In fact, it appears that `decay()` was added in the r8 revision at the San Diego meeting, November 2018.